# NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch equivalent in Android

Tags: java, android, search, dictionary

NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch  in Xcode is a function that helps searching without taking care of the accent ex: "e"="é". This function shows the user all the results of the words starting/having "e" and "é" whether the user enters "e" or "é" 
What is the equivalent of this function on the android platform??

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Android (or Java really) does not offer anything like this out of the box.  However you can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents%28java.lang.String%29) `StringUtils.stripAccents` method to strip accents from both the search string and sought string and then do the searches.  So, instead of searching for `string1` inside `string2`, you would be searching for `StringUtils.stripAccents(string1)` inside `StringUtils.stripAccents(string2)`.
It's not exactly the same thing, but it should get you reasonably close.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reduce your problem to comparing a pairs of strings, the `java.text.Collator` ([SE 7 JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html), [Android JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html)) provides a base for comparing two strings using different "strength" modes: `PRIMARY` will differentiate between "e" and "é" characters while `SECONDARY` will treat them as equal.